# calculate the sum of values based on the input and match

Tags: php

To calculate the sum of values based on the input and match it with names in an array

```
$input = '500';

    $array1 = array("200" => 'jhon',"300" => 'puppy',"50" => 'liza',
"150" => 'rehana',"400" => 'samra',"100" => 'bolda',);
```

need answer  like this output

```
jhon,puppy and bolda,rehana
```

This code creates an array $data that contains names and their respective values. It then uses a foreach loop to iterate through the array and subtract the value of each name from the input until the input becomes zero. The names of all the values that were subtracted from the input are stored in an array $names. Finally, if the array $names is not empty, the names are echoed using implode separated by "and". If the array is empty, it means no match was found and a message "No match found" is echoed.

Comment: Hi. You should repeat the wording of the question. It's not clear. Also give us a reproducible example. What you've tried, what you get and want. As it stands, I don't think anyone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm going to go out on a guess here. (this sounds like cheating on homework lmao).

You need to output pairs of names where the two names add upto 500 (the input).

This probably wont be the most optimal solution, but it should be a solution that works?

```php
$input = 500;

// using shorthand array formatting

$array1 = [
    200 => 'jhon',
    300 => 'puppy',
    50 => 'liza',
    150 => 'rehana',
    400 => 'samra',
    100 => 'bolda'
];

// create an array that holds names we have already processed.
$namesProcessed = [];

// loop over the names trying to find a compatible partner

foreach ($array1 as $points => $name) {
    
    foreach ($array1 as $pointsPotentialPartner => $namePotentialPartner) {

        // Don't partner with yourself...
        if ($name == $namePotentialPartner) {
            continue;
        }

        // Don't partner with someone that has already been processed.
        if (in_array($namePotentialPartner, $namesProcessed)) {
            continue;
        }

        // test if the two partners add up to the input
        if ($input == ($points + $pointsPotentialPartner)) {

           // if this is the first partner set, don't put in 'and'

           if (count($namesProcessed) == 0) {
               echo $name . ', ' . $namePotentialPartner;
           } else {
               echo ' and ' . $name . ', ' . $namePotentialPartner;
           }

           $namesProcessed[] = $name;
           $namesProcessed[] = $namePotentialPartner;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: very very thanks brother great ans you solved my problem brother